# Firebase DocumentReference.get() query extremely slow in Safari only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, safari, database-performance

I'm using Firebase/Firestore 7.14.4 for data storage in a single page web app. On Chrome, Firefox, and others, the app performs just fine. In Safari, however, on both Mac and iOS, the first call after login to `DocumentReference.get()` takes minutes and minutes, or indeed never completes. This occurs:

- when the document in question is large (1 MB)
- when the document in question is tiny, just two date fields
- when all caches have been cleared
- when caches have not been cleared

The code that produces this problem could not be simpler.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( async (user) => {
  if( user ) {
    const userDoc = db.collection( 'users' ).doc( user.uid );
    const docSnapshot = await userDoc.get();    // <- .get() never returns
    // ...
  }
}
```

Again, this happens only on Mac and iOS Safari, not in Chrome or Firefox.

Anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: If you have a bug report, I suggest filing it on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this trivial example in both Chrome and Safari:

```
var start = Date.now();
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    firebase.firestore().doc("61881285/me").get().then(function(doc) {
      console.log(`Signed in and got doc in ${Date.now()-start}ms`);
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  }
});
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/rokafac/4/edit?js,console)

The results:

- Chrome: "Signed in and got doc in 528ms"
- Safari: "Signed in and got doc in 327ms"

Let me know if you get different results when you run the jsbin.

If you are getting different results with your code but not the above, I'd love to see a similar example that we can run to reproduce those results.

Comment: That's helpful. It helped me to find a workaround. In my program (I can't get jsbin to accept this code), if I add: `db.enablePersistence( { synchronizeTabs: true } );`, the problem occurs. If I remove it, it doesn't occur. Perhaps there's a bug with `enablePersistence()`, or `synchronizeTabs`, on Safari?

Comment: Your jsbin works for me. If I inject the `db.enablePersistence()` line right after the `db` assignment, I get a script error. I've not used jsbin so I don't know if this is a problem with library inclusion, or what. https://jsbin.com/qayedetipu/1/edit?js,console